# Android: mock Resources.openRawResource(int)

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm trying to test some code that makes the call `context.getResources().openRawResource(rawResourceId)` ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#openRawResource(int))), where the resource is a text file to be read from.

My test class extends `AndroidTestCase`.

How would I be able to mock this call to return whatever file contents I want?

Comment: Are you using the new Unit Test support? Are you using Robolectric?

Comment: @Emmanuel sorry I should've been more specific, my test class extends AndroidTestCase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your able to set the `Context` of the code you're testing, you can do this by creating the following two classes (I tend to make them private classes within my test class because they contain test specific information):

```
private class mMockContext extends MockContext {

    @Override
    public Resources getResources() {
        return new mMockResources();
    }
}

private class mMockResources extends MockResources {

    @Override
    public InputStream openRawResource(int id) {
        String fileContents = "line one\n" +
        "line two\n" +
        "line three";

        return new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContents.getBytes());
    }
}
```

Then, when you're creating your class to be tested, pass it the `mMockContext` class in place of the `Context`.

Comment: That'll do it. Thanks!